# Input (keyboard/mouse/touch pad) doesn't work while on integrated graphics

Tags: release-hera, keyboard

I have integrated intel and discrete nvidia graphics. After an update my input stopped working while I'm using intel as soon as I log into desktop environment. Looks like updating nvidia drivers from 450 to 460 version broke something. When nvidia card in use there are no issues.I've tried to reinstall xorg input but it didn't help. Is it possible to bring it back to life without reinstalling the os?

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the input troubles for me:

1. choose `on-demand` option in nvidia prime-profile and reboot
2. choose `intel` option from the prime-profile and reboot
3. that's it: strangely enough keyboard/touch pad are working while in on integrated intel graphics.